# Rails ActiveRecord 'slightly' complex Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I would like to structure a music web-application's database to use the following structure.

**Song(Attributes: name, year, etc(any other relevant attributes))**

- has many **Performances**
- has many **Performers** (through **Performances**)
- has many **Artists** (through **Performers**)

**Performance(Foreign key:Song_id, Attributes: enum version: [:official, :remix, :cover])**

- belongs to **Song**
- has many **Performers**
- has many **Artists** (through **Performers**)

**Performers (Foreign keys: Performance_id, Artist_id, Attributes: enum role: [:main_artist, :collaborating_artist, :featuring_artist, :versus ])**

- has one **Song** (through **Performers**)
- belongs to **Performances**
- belongs to **Artist**

**Artist(Attributes: name, DOB, etc.(any other relevant attributes))**

- has many **Performers**
- has many **Performances** (through **Performers**)
- has many **Songs** (through **Performances**)

So that upon saving a Song, i can have all the rest of the other tables populated too, that is via the associations, however, so far i had the following implementations:

Song model:

```
    class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

        #Added to make the db more logical and ended up complicated
        has_many :performances
        has_many :performers, :through => :performances
        has_many :artists, :through => :performers

        accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, allow_destroy: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :performers, allow_destroy: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :performances, allow_destroy: true

        validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: true
        validates :year, :presence => true
    end
```

Performance model:

```
   class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
      enum version: [:official, :remix, :cover]

      belongs_to :song
      has_many :performers
      has_many :artists, :through => :performers
    end
```

Performer model:

```
   class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
      enum role: [:main_artist, :collaborating_artist, :featuring_artist, :versus]

      belongs_to :artist
      belongs_to :performance
      has_one :song, :through => :performers #this upsets the back hairs!
    end
```

Artist model:

```
    class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

        #Added to make the db more logical and ended up complicated
        has_many :performers
        has_many :performances, :through => :performers
        has_many :songs, :through => :performances

        validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: true
    end
```

Song controller

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
     ...
    end

    def new
       @song = Song.new
       @song.performers.build
       @song.performances.build
       @genres = Genre.all #.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
       @countries = Country.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end

   def create
      @song = Song.new(song_params)
      if @song.save
        redirect_to @song, notice: 'Successfully added a song.'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
   end

   def show
      ...
   end

   def update
      if @song.update(song_params)
         redirect_to @song, notice: 'Successfully updated the song.'
      else
         render 'edit', notice: 'Unable to save the changes'
      end
   end

   def edit
      ... 
   end

   def destroy
      ...
   end

   private 

   def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:name, :year, artists_attributes: [ :id, :name, :DOB], performances_attributes: [:id, :version, :song_id], performers_attributes: [:id, :performance_id, :artist_id]) 

   end

   def find_song
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
    <div class="content">
        <%= form_for @song, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

            <% if @song.errors.any? %>
                <div>
                    <%= @song.errors.count %>
                    Prevented this song from saving
                    <ul>
                        <% @song.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                            <li><%= msg %></li>
                        <% end %>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :name %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "input-field"  %>
            </div>

            <div class="song-version">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.fields_for :performances do |performances_for_form| %>
                        <%= render 'performances_fields', f: performances_for_form %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="performers-fields">
                <h2>Artist(s)</h2>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.fields_for :performers do |performers_for_form| %>
                        <%= render 'performers_fields', f: performers_for_form %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class"btn">
                <%= f.submit %> 
            </div>

        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Performance partial

```
    <fieldset>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :version %>
          <%= f.select :version, Performance.versions.keys %>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Performer partial

```
    <fieldset>  
        <h2>Artists Details</h2>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.fields_for :artists do |artists_for_form| %>
                <%= render 'artist_fields', f: artists_for_form %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :artists_role %>
          <%= f.select :role, Performer.roles.keys %>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Artist partial

```
    <fieldset>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :DOB %>
          <%= f.datetime_select :DOB, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

When I fill out all the data on the form, upon saving, only the **Song's attributes** and **Performances attributes** are saved to the database, while the **Performers & Artists** are never saved, neither is the connection established, my questions are:

- Is this structure logically correct? If not what is it that is being incorrectly done.
- Is the `new, create methods` of `songs_controller` wrongly implemented and thus, the reason for not being able to save the data appropriately?
- What right and or best practices could be employed developing this type of web-application with this kind of database structure?
- Or is there any other better or succinct database structure that would better be followed rather than this?

Comment: You're probably taking the right approach but just need to debug. Try using byebug

Comment: Look closely at the log files to see what the actual params are being passed into the create action of the song controller. Check that they meet the expectations of the class rather than your expectations. Try copying and pasting the params hash into a rails console session and use them to create a song, using logger.debug statements in the song model to see what happens. Your db structure is sound and your associations look fine to me

Comment: @jamesaw tried but now i am getting this error:  **ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection in SongsController#create
Cannot modify association 'Song#performers' because the source reflection class 'Performer' is associated to 'Performance' via :has_many.**

Comment: @maxpleaner will try that, although after this error, i'm suspecting some kind of misfit somewhere in the associations.